# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager with HTTP and HTTPS base url

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking, afhttprequestoperation

I was wondering what is the best option (architecture) for situation where I have same API on HTTP and HTTPS. Is there a way to support HTTP and HTTPS requests in same `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` or should I have two subclasses, one for HTTP requests and second for HTTPS requests?

I feel like changing `baseURL` dynamically is not the best solution

Comment: Note that you can't change `baseURL` given that it's a `readonly` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold two AFHTTPClient* objects. One for http and other for secure https. 
Here is example based on my Requester class.

-- Requester.h ---

```
#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

typedef enum
{
    MultipartTypeImageJPEG,
    MultipartTypeImagePNG,
    MultipartTypeVideoQuicktime
} MultipartType;

typedef enum
{
    HTTPMethodGET,
    HTTPMethodPOST,
    HTTPMethodPUT,
    HTTPMethodDELETE
} HTTPMethod;

typedef void (^RequestCallback)(NSError *error, NSInteger statusCode, id json);

@interface Requester : NSObject

/**
 * Singleton
 */
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

- (void)requestToPath:(NSString *)path
               method:(HTTPMethod)method
               params:(NSDictionary *)params
             complete:(RequestCallback)callback;

- (void)requestMultipartToPath:(NSString *)path
                        method:(HTTPMethod)method
                        params:(NSDictionary *)params
                      fileData:(NSData *)fileData
                      fileName:(NSString *)fileName
                          type:(MultipartType)multyPartType
                      complete:(RequestCallback)callback;


- (void)secureRequestToPath:(NSString *)path
              method:(HTTPMethod)method
              params:(NSDictionary *)params
            complete:(RequestCallback)callback;
```

-- Requester.m ---

```
#import "Requester.h"

@interface Requester()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPClient *httpClient;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPClient *httpClientSecure;

@end

@implementation Requester

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static id instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}

+ (void)initialize
{
    [super initialize];


    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_BASE_ADDRESS_HTTP];
    NSURL *secureBaseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_BASE_ADDRESS_HTTPS];

    [Requester sharedInstance].httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [Requester sharedInstance].httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;

    [Requester sharedInstance].httpClientSecure = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:secureBaseURL];
    [Requester sharedInstance].httpClientSecure.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;

}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //...
    }
    return self;
}


#pragma mak - Request Types
- (NSMutableURLRequest*)requestWithPathPOST:(NSString*)path withParams:(NSDictionary*)params
{
    params = [self addRequiredBodyProperties:params];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:params];
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData;
    request = [self addRequiredHeaderProperties:request];

    return request;
}

- (NSMutableURLRequest*)requestWithPathGET:(NSString*)path withParams:(NSDictionary*)params
{
    params = [self addRequiredBodyProperties:params];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:params];
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData;
    request = [self addRequiredHeaderProperties:request];

    return request;
}

- (NSMutableURLRequest*)requestWithPathPUT:(NSString*)path withParams:(NSDictionary*)params
{
    params = [self addRequiredBodyProperties:params];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.httpClient requestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:path parameters:params];
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData;
    request = [self addRequiredHeaderProperties:request];

    return request;
}

- (NSMutableURLRequest*)requestWithPathDEL:(NSString*)path withParams:(NSDictionary*)params
{
    params = [self addRequiredBodyProperties:params];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.httpClient requestWithMethod:@"DELETE" path:path parameters:params];
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData;
    request = [self addRequiredHeaderProperties:request];

    return request;
}

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)addRequiredHeaderProperties:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[request allHTTPHeaderFields] mutableCopy];

    // Here adding some header parameters that required on every request
    NSString *deviceId = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    [dic setObject:deviceId forKey:@"Device-Id"];          
    [dic setObject:@"ios" forKey:@"os"];

    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:dic];

    return request;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)addRequiredBodyProperties:(NSDictionary *)params
{
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [params mutableCopy];
    if (!result) {
        result = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    }

    // Here adding some parameters that required on every request
    if (API_KEY) {
        [result setObject:API_KEY forKey:@"api_key"];
    }


    return result;
}

- (NSMutableURLRequest*)requestMultipartWithPath:(NSString*)path method:(NSString *)method withParams:(NSDictionary*)params fileData:(NSData *)fileData fileName:(NSString *)fileName type:(MultipartType)multyPartType
{
    params = [self addRequiredBodyProperties:params];

    NSString *mimeType = @"";
    NSString *name = @"picture";
    switch (multyPartType) {
        case MultipartTypeImageJPEG:

            mimeType = @"image/jpeg";
            if (fileName)
            {
                if ([fileName rangeOfString:@".jpg"].location == NSNotFound && [fileName rangeOfString:@".jpeg"].location == NSNotFound)
                {
                    fileName = [fileName stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
                }
            }
            break;
        case MultipartTypeImagePNG:

            mimeType = @"image/png";
            if (fileName)
            {
                if ([fileName rangeOfString:@".png"].location == NSNotFound)
                {
                    fileName = [fileName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
                }
            }

            break;
        case MultipartTypeVideoQuicktime:
            mimeType = @"video/quicktime";
            name = @"video";
            break;
    }

    if (!method || [method isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        method = @"POST";
    }

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:method path:path parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData name:name fileName:fileName mimeType:mimeType];
    }];

    request = [self addRequiredHeaderProperties:request];

    return request;
}

#pragma mark - Global Requests

- (void)JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request callback:(RequestCallback)callback
{
    [[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        if (callback) {
            callback(nil,response.statusCode,O);
        }

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
        NSLog(@"%@",JSON);

        if (callback) {
            callback(error,response.statusCode,JSON);
        }
    }] start];
}

#pragma mark -

- (void)requestToPath:(NSString *)path method:(HTTPMethod)method params:(NSDictionary *)params complete:(RequestCallback)callback
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
    switch (method) {
        case HTTPMethodGET:
            request = [self requestWithPathGET:path withParams:params];
            break;
        case HTTPMethodPUT:
            request = [self requestWithPathPUT:path withParams:params];
            break;
        case HTTPMethodPOST:
            request = [self requestWithPathPOST:path withParams:params];
            break;
        case HTTPMethodDELETE:
            request = [self requestWithPathDEL:path withParams:params];
            break;
    }

    [self JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request callback:callback];
}

- (void)requestMultipartToPath:(NSString *)path method:(HTTPMethod)method params:(NSDictionary *)params fileData:(NSData *)fileData fileName:(NSString *)fileName type:(MultipartType)multyPartType complete:(RequestCallback)callback
{
    NSString *methodString = @"";
    switch (method) {
        case HTTPMethodGET:
            methodString = @"GET";
            break;
        case HTTPMethodPUT:
            methodString = @"PUT";
            break;
        case HTTPMethodPOST:
            methodString = @"POST";
            break;
        case HTTPMethodDELETE:
            methodString = @"DELETE";
            break;
    }

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestMultipartWithPath:path method:methodString withParams:params fileData:fileData fileName:fileName type:multyPartType];
    [self JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request callback:callback];
}

- (void)secureRequestToPath:(NSString *)path method:(HTTPMethod)method params:(NSDictionary *)params complete:(RequestCallback)callback
{    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
    switch (method) {
        case HTTPMethodGET:
            request = [self.httpClientSecure requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:params];
            break;
        case HTTPMethodPUT:
            request = [self.httpClientSecure requestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:path parameters:params];
            break;
        case HTTPMethodPOST:
            request = [self.httpClientSecure requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:params];
            break;
        case HTTPMethodDELETE:
            request = [self.httpClientSecure requestWithMethod:@"DELETE" path:path parameters:params];
            break;
    }

    AFJSONRequestOperation *oper = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {                                                         

                                                         if (callback) {
                                                             callback(nil,response.statusCode,JSON);
                                                         }
      } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
          NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
          NSLog(@"%@",JSON);

          if (callback) {
              callback(error,response.statusCode,JSON);
          }
      }];

    [oper start];
}
@end
```

Usage:

For http:

```
 [[Requester sharedInstance] requestToPath:@"user/authenticate"
                                                       method:HTTPMethodPOST
                                                       params:@{@"username":username,@"password":password}
                                                     complete:^(NSError *error, NSInteger statusCode, id json) {
                                                         if (!error) {
                                                             //do something with response
                                                         }

                                                     }];
```

For https:

```
 [[Requester sharedInstance] secureRequestToPath:@"user/authenticate"
                                                       method:HTTPMethodPOST
                                                       params:@{@"username":username,@"password":password}
                                                     complete:^(NSError *error, NSInteger statusCode, id json) {
                                                         if (!error) {
                                                             //do something with response
                                                         }

                                                     }];
```